# Get field value of inserted row

Tags: mysql, sql, function, primary-key, return-value

I want to write a function that returns the value of a column (in this case, an auto-incrementing primary key) for a row that it inserts.

Essentially, I want to insert some new data, have a new primary key generated, then get that key. I could simply look for the highest primary key in the table, but it is possible that someone else could be running the function as well, and I could return the wrong key, right?

What's the simplest way to negotiate this problem?

Comment: `last_insert_id()`:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id.

Comment: Will that not have the problem I mentioned in the original post about possibly getting an ID I don't want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in the comments, from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

```
mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
    -> 195
```

This `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function is not subject to a race condition like `SELECT MAX(id)` might be, because it's maintained within MySQL specific to your connection. It returns the ID generated for *your* last insert, not *anybody's* last insert.